# Stk086 distance between pins?

Tags: amplifier, powermosfet, power-amplifier

I have been trying to make a footprint for this IC, and trying to figure out the distance between pins, it is a 10 pin ic what do you think the distance will be?
What is the normal distance between pins? 
I don't have the IC right now that's why i cannot measure it so it would be great if someone will help me.

Comment: It should have a datasheet. And the datasheet has all of the numbers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is a very old ic and it's datasheet doesn't have that information I've checked already.

Comment: Do you have the part? Then take a caliper and measure...

Comment: I haven't bought it from china but it is gonna get here next month but i have to design pcb before it arrives here.

Comment: Are you telling me that you are designing some *new* circuit and planning to use some *old* and obsolete part for it?

Comment: There are tons of possible packages and all of them have very different pin spacing. Does it say what the package is? Is it SOIC? TSSOP? SIP? TO-220?

Comment: @davidweb where is that datasheet you're referring to? Could you please link to it? Also, as Eugene says: Audio amplifiers have only gotten better and simpler and cheaper in the last decades. It's probably a bad idea to make a new board with an old amplifier.

Comment: designs on
the National Semiconductor LM1875
20W chip and the Philips TDA1562Q
bridge amplifier. ... these give better performance than the STK086.

Comment: https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/S/T/K/STK080_ETC.pdf
 
this is the data sheet, and i am using this IC Because my BOSS is a old school guy who wants me to make an amplifier circuit specifically with this IC and i cannot make him understand that this is not 90's.

Comment: You would need a fan+ large heatsink to get more than 20W   .... the ones I suggested are much lower THD

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist yes i am gonna have to keep that in mind too but first i need to make foot prints for this ic.

Comment: without good datasheet, it is a very bad plan with obsolete parts  get the TI or NXP parts and design from datasheet

Comment: **That data sheet is not the same product that's in your title!**

Answer (score 3):

[Found a datasheet for the NTE1337.](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/1300to1399/pdf/nte1337.pdf)

It is a replacement for the STK086.

The datasheet for the NTE1337 includes this drawing:

[image]

It shows the package size, hole sizes and locations, and the pin spacing (as well as pin dimensions.)  The measurements seem to match those that @KingDuken found, but are easier to read.

You will need all that it has to offer since you will have to design your hardware such that you can attach that chip to a (big) heatsink.  It is rated for 70W output power - the wasted power will probably be at least that much.

If you can find a copy of the "STK and STR Integrated Circuits" book, you will find the ECG1337 and the NTE1337 listed as replacements for the STK086.

Comment: WTG JRE  attaboy

Answer (score 1):

Next time before you order something, I recommend doing some better research. You specified a part and ordered this without 1) considering your physical spacing and 2) not asking a supplier about the physical dimensions.

I managed to dig up a datasheet (for the STK-080) that had the same form factor. The link you provided demonstrated that the picture will be appropriate for what you're looking for since it provided specifications for the STK-075, 077, 078, 080, 082, and 083. I also saw another datasheet for the STK-084, 085, and 086, and it has the same form factor so I believe the picture below will still be applicable. [Try this link out](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/41476/SANYO/STK-0080/127/1/STK-0080.html) for more details.

[image]

I did my best to place a sharpened mask in the picture so that it's easier to read.